# Implementing twitter audio card like soundcloud

Tags: audio, twitter, soundcloud, twitter-card

I want to implement audio card like soundclound, basically when I made audio card it was working fine in web, but when I tried playing same card in mobile app but it was redirecting to web browser. so the thing is I want my audio to play in the app itself not to redirect and open a new page on web . let me know if anyone has some idea about implementation of the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to implement an audio card for yourself would be to use Twitter's [player card](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/type/player) option. On mobile, that will end up redirecting to a browser.

The Soundcloud card is a special card implemented by Twitter, and is not generally available to other sites.

Comment: Yeah that's what is there any way others can also make sound card like that or it is not at possible. Anchor fm also have audio card like soundcloud.

Comment: These are not generally available, no.